# Pivot and Groupby with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
DECLARANT   PARTNER PRODUCT PERIOD  VALUE   KG
FR          XC      1001    200501  10      20
FR          XC      1002    200501  11      21
FR          XC      1001    200502  12      22
FR          XC      1002    200502  13      23
FR          XC      1003    200502  14      24
```

And I want it transformed into something like this:

```
DECLARANT   PARTNER     PRODUCT  VALUE      KG
FR          XC          1001     [10,12]    [20,22]
FR          XC          1002     [11,13]    [21,23]
FR          XC          1003     [nan,14]   [nan,24]
```

That is, the `VALUE` and `KG` is pivoted based on `PERIOD`, and if it doesn't exist in the `PERIOD` it should be replaced with `nan`.

I've tried [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). But don't seem to get them to work together. This kind-of gives me something but not really what I'm looking for:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['DECLARANT','PARTNER','PRODUCT'],
                                      columns=['PERIOD'],
                                      values=['KG', 'VALUE'])
```

Comment: When you're pivoting, you need to specifiy an aggregate function to tell it what to do at the cell level - often this might be something like sum, or a count of constituent values. 
In your case, it looks like you want to aggregate the contents into a list - you'll need a function for that - and `list` may actually do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` per columns and aggregate `list`s:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index=['DECLARANT','PARTNER','PRODUCT'],
                                      columns=['PERIOD'],
                                      values=['KG', 'VALUE'])
         .groupby(axis=1, level=0)
         .apply(lambda x: x.agg(list, 1)))
print (df)
                                     KG         VALUE
DECLARANT PARTNER PRODUCT                            
FR        XC      1001     [20.0, 22.0]  [10.0, 12.0]
                  1002     [21.0, 23.0]  [11.0, 13.0]
                  1003      [nan, 24.0]   [nan, 14.0]
```